# How to generate link dynamically in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I am developing a new wcf service which will be hosted in IIS.  This service should generate a link dynamically for each customer and provide same to customer. This link always points an executable file. How do we generate dynamic links to each customer?

Comment: What have you done so far? This sounds like a homework or your daily job for me, and without efforts expressed, SO will hardly help you.

Comment: If you don’t want to answer, fine. But no need be sarcastic, , it’s neither homework nor daily job for you.

Comment: It's not about not wanting to answer, neither about sarcasm. SO is community  driven, we help each other, not directly do each other's work.

Comment: I am not asking to do my work. I have done my homework on this and found that we can use virtual directory for this purpose. I have posted this question as I am new IIS and check any better approaches.Again I want to say that I am not asking anyone to do my work,

Comment: Without seeing your current solution it’s hard to provide a “better one”… that’s what I actually asked from you, so we can actually help.

Comment: I agree that it was my mistake that I didn't include the current solution. I have no issues to explain my current solution as well. But only issue is the way you have asked "This sounds like a homework or your daily job for me".

Comment: You should provide some piece code, it's hard to just pop up a any idea to help you this way.